# cannot run my android app on actual device or AVD

Tags: android

Iam doing some android development using android studio 2.0, recently Iam failing in running any app neither in my actual device nor on my AVD. I have make the last updates required for android studio and SDK.

Here are some of the error messages:

```
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iam doing some android development using android studio 2.0, recently Iam failing in running any app neither in my acti](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595952/iam-doing-some-android-development-using-android-studio-2-0-recently-iam-failin)

Comment: show the full stack trace

Comment: please don´t ask questions twice....delete one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by checking the `Use in-process build` in the compiler settings.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> → `Build, Execution, Deployment` → `Compiler`

[image]